# Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON after Angular / dependencies update

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have updated my project to Angular 9 and updated some dependencies like Firebase.
My app works fine in the dev environment, but doesn't work when I build it for production with the command 'ng build --prod --configuration production'. Ivy has been disabled.
I get a white page when running the production build.

Chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 's'
> |     property '_zoneDelegate' -> object with constructor 'u'
> --- property 'zone' closes the circle

> ```
> at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
> at pe.handleError (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at Object.next (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at c.i [as _next] (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at c.__tryOrUnsub (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at c.next (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at u._next (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at u.next (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at Ym.next (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at Ym.emit (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1
> at u.invoke (polyfills-es2015.a65c2e23b6b4c1b0f110.js:1)
> at s.run (polyfills-es2015.a65c2e23b6b4c1b0f110.js:1)
> at Y_.runOutsideAngular (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at Object.onHandleError (main-es2015.9c7d580a30948a4f7bd8.js:1)
> at u.handleError (polyfills-es2015.a65c2e23b6b4c1b0f110.js:1)
> at s.runGuarded (polyfills-es2015.a65c2e23b6b4c1b0f110.js:1)
> at Object.n.microtaskDrainDone (polyfills-es2015.a65c2e23b6b4c1b0f110.js:1)
> at m (polyfills-es2015.a65c2e23b6b4c1b0f110.js:1)
> ```

Sentry screenshot:

[image: Sentry screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. It was an issue with the NgForage library, it was supposed to be compatible with Angular 9, but it doesn't seem to work. Removing NgForage from app.module.ts and services fixes the production build